# JavaScript: 1 undefined value in Promise.all results

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to break down promises, as I want to eventually return the results of an SQL query within the `myPromise` promise, so that I end of with a list of the results of a many SQL queries.

```js
var myList = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    myList.push(myPromise);
    resolve("ITEM " + i);
  })
}

Promise.all(myList).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});

console.log("End");
```

Output:

```
[ undefined,
  'ITEM 1',
  'ITEM 2',
  'ITEM 3',
  'ITEM 4',
  'ITEM 5',
  'ITEM 6',
  'ITEM 7',
  'ITEM 8',
  'ITEM 9',
  'ITEM 10',
  'ITEM 11',
  'ITEM 12',
  'ITEM 13',
  'ITEM 14',
  'ITEM 15',
  'ITEM 16',
  'ITEM 17',
  'ITEM 18',
  'ITEM 19' ]
```

*How I understand how it works:* My loop immediately appends a new promise to `myList`, then when it's resolved the promise gets replaced with the string value from passed into `resolve`.

It works well but I end up with 1 undefined value at the beginning. I have 20 items total which is expected, but one is undefined. Why is this?

Comment: have you tried to put the resolve() call before the myList.push() ??

Comment: @EduardoJunior same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `myPromise` you push to `myList` is created *after* the Promise constructor runs. So, on the first iteration, `myPromise` is `undefined` (and on subsequent iterations, the *last `myPromise`* is pushed to the array).

Construct the Promise, and then *immediately* push to the array in the same iteration instead:

```js
var myList = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("ITEM " + i);
  });
  myList.push(myPromise);
}
Promise.all(myList).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});

console.log("End");
```

It might be clearer if you manually hoist the `myPromise` (so that you see the code closer to how the interpreter runs it):

```js
var myPromise;
var myList = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("ITEM " + i);
  });
  myList.push(myPromise);
}
Promise.all(myList).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});

console.log("End");
```

Answer (score 3):

The first time, you are pushing `myPromise` to `myList` while it is still undefined.

You can fix this by avoiding the `myPromise` variable altogether.

```
var myList = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    myList.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("ITEM " + i);
    }))
}
```

or pushing to `myList` afterwards.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("ITEM " + i);
    })
    myList.push(myPromise);
}
```